# Xamarin Android app can't be deployed to the VS2019 emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to solve this for a while now, I followed this guide up to this point: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/xamarin/hello-world-tutorial/devicesetup but once I click on the Android Emulator I get this message [image]

To which I click Install, but nothing happens and it's an endless loop, right after that if I click on NEW, I have no device recognized.
Am I missing an installation process? Knowing that I followed the Xamarin guide literally.
Thank you.

Comment: Before that you need to confirm if you had installed the Android SDK . Open the SDK Manager(beside to the device manager) to check if you had installed at least an Android SDK.

Comment: Hello, yes I have Android SDK platform 28 & 29 both installed.

Comment: Post the issue to Help->Send Feedback->Report a problem .